# Appends new item to end of list with the value (last item + 1)

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to define a function where: This function takes a single argument which is a list name itself. It will then look at the value of the last existing item in the list, it will then append a new value that is one unit bigger. This is what I have:

```
    my_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

    def add_item_to_list(ordered_list):
        for (num[-1]) in ordered_list:
        ordered_list.append(num[-1] + 1)
    # Appends new item to end of list with the value (last item + 1)
```

But I get this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in add_item_to_list
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

Comment: If you only want to append one item, why are you looping over the entire list?

Comment: btw there is no loop in the code for multiple reasons, most of them syntactic.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need no `for-loop`:

```
my_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

def add_item_to_list(ordered_list):
    ordered_list.append(ordered_list[-1] + 1)
    return ordered_list

print(add_item_to_list(my_list))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have code which does as you describe

```
def add_item_to_list(ordered_list):
    last_item = ordered_list[-1]
    ordered_list.append(list_item + 1)
```